# How to solve the Maximum call stack size exceeded issue in JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application

As shown below I am using knockout. I have multiple view models which I am combining and passing through to the controller . The problem is that when I run the application, upon clicking <kbd>F12</kbd> to check for errors while the browser is open I came across this small issue:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```js
function FullEmployeeProfile ()
{
    var EmployeeEdu = new employeeEducation();
    var EmployeeHist =  new employeeEducation();
    var EmpInfo = new employeeEducation();  

}
function employeeInfo() {
    var ei = this;

     var ei = this;
        ei.Name = ko.observable("");
        ei.ID = ko.observable("");
        ei.Gender = ko.observable("");
        ei.address = ko.observable("") ;     
    }
function employeeHistory() {
        var eh = this 

         var self = this;
        eh.CompanyName = ko.observable();
        eh.Designation = ko.observable();
        eh.StartDate = ko.observable();
        eh.EndDate = ko.observable();
}

function employeeEducation() {
    var ee = this;
        ee.Degree = ko.observable();
        ee.YearOfPassing = ko.observable();
        ee.Percentage = ko.observable();
        ee.Institute = ko.observable()


    ee.fullEmployeeDetails = new FullEmployeeProfile();
    ee.saveEmployeeDetails = function() {

        $.when(postSecureData("/api/EmployeeProfile/", ko.toJSON(ee.fullEmployeeDetails)))
        .done(function (empProfile) {
            if (response.ResponseRequired == false) {
            document.getElementById("save-empDetails-btn").innerHTML = "Saving...";
            setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("save-empDetails-btn").innerHTML = "Save" }, 2500);
            $.msgGrowl({
                type: 'info',
                title: 'Employee information saved',


        }); }

        });
    };

}
```

Comment: You seem to have pasted the `function employeeEducation` definition  twice.

Comment: @RoyJ  thank you for pointing that out I have made the necessary adjustments

Comment: Your FullEmployeeProfile should be initializing member variables (based on `this`) rather than local (`var`) variables. Right now, it constructs an empty object for `ee.fullEmployeeDetails`

Comment: @RoyJ I changed that as you suggested but it doesnt seem to solve the "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" issue

Comment: That's why I didn't post it as an answer. :)
The error generally happens due to infinite recursion: a function calls itself (or another function that calls the first function, or whatever). I don't see that in the code you've posted here.
Some things you have done are not very knockout in style, for example setting `innerHTML` -- those should be done with text bindings. Again, not the source of the problem, but would make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I got your problem. your code is stucking in infinite function calls which is causing your browser's stack size exceeding.

when Your function `employeeEducation()` gets executed, Then its behavior is as follows (see line between commented lines):

```
function employeeEducation() {
    var ee = this;
        ee.Degree = ko.observable();
        ee.YearOfPassing = ko.observable();
        ee.Percentage = ko.observable();
        ee.Institute = ko.observable()

//........................................................
    ee.fullEmployeeDetails = new FullEmployeeProfile();
//................................................
    ee.saveEmployeeDetails = function() {

        $.when(postSecureData("/api/EmployeeProfile/", ko.toJSON(ee.fullEmployeeDetails)))
        .done(function (empProfile) {
            if (response.ResponseRequired == false) {
            document.getElementById("save-empDetails-btn").innerHTML = "Saving...";
            setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("save-empDetails-btn").innerHTML = "Save" }, 2500);
            $.msgGrowl({
                type: 'info',
                title: 'Employee information saved',


        }); }

        });
    };
```

See highlighted text above, which calls `FullEmployeeProfile()` constructor. And execute Following (Focus on the line between commented lines):

```
function FullEmployeeProfile ()

{
    var EmployeeEdu = new employeeEducation();
    var EmployeeHist =  new employeeEducation();
//.......................................................
    var EmpInfo = new employeeEducation();
//...........................................................

}
```

And, in above code it'll execute `employeeEducation()` again, which in-turn execute  **`ee.fullEmployeeDetails = new FullEmployeeProfile();`** statement which calls `FullEmployeeProfile()` constructor, and so on . It continues infinitely until your browser's stack size exceeded.

**This situation is like: A is calling B where B is calling A...**

Try changing your code.